# Finding linear orders on a measure space whose initial segments have all possible measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mu$ be a non-atomic probability measure on some space $(X, \Sigma)$.

Is it always possible to find a linear order, $\leq$, on $X$ such that $\mu: \mathcal{A}\rightarrow [0,1]$ is surjective, where $\mathcal{A}=\{\{y : y\leq x\} : x\in X\}$? If so, is it possible to strengthen that to bijectivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the atomlessness of $\mu$, inductively construct a binary tree $\langle X_{\sigma} : \sigma \in 2^{< \omega}\rangle$ such that $X_{\phi} = X$ and for each $\sigma$, $X_{\sigma 0}, X_{\sigma 1}$ partition $X_{\sigma}$ into two sets of equal measure. For each $f \in 2^{\omega}$, let $X_f = \bigcap_n X_{f \upharpoonright n}$. Note that each $X_f$ is $\mu$-null. Let $<_f$ be an arbitrary linear order on $X_f$. For $x, y \in X$ defined $x< y$ iff *either* for some $f \in 2^{\omega}$, $x, y \in X_f$ and $x <_f y$ *or* for some $f \neq g \in 2^{\omega}$, $x \in X_f, y \in X_g$ and $f < g$ in lexicographic order. Now check.